Example of an element in some ring which is nilpotent but not strictly nilpotent
Definition. An element $a$ of ring $R$ is called strictly nilpotent if for any sequence $(a_i)_{i=0}^{\infty}$ such that $a_0 = a$ and $a_{i+1} \in a_i R a_i, \, i \ge 1$ there exists a zero element $a_j = 0$.
Is exists an example of such element in some ring which is nilpotent but not strictly nilpotent?

For example, can you show there is a ring with nonzero elements $x, y$ such that $x^2 = 0$ but $xyx \ne 0$ and $xyxyxyx \ne 0$ and so on..? (Any example must be noncommutative, of course)

@Izaak van Dongen $R = M_2 (\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and $x = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $y = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Is't it?

Don't use mathjax to tyleset bold or italic text. Use mark-up.
